# Django, I have added endif but it still shows an error?

Tags: django

my code

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li> <a href="#">Post</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Groups</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Create Group</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Log Out</a> </li>
      {% else %}
        <li> <a href="#">Groups</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Log In</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}">Sign Up</a> </li>
      {& endif %}
```

error shown is
 Unclosed tag on line 30: 'if'. Looking for one of: endif.

Comment: sorry, i found the error, it was in the syntax

Answer (score 2):

You have {& endif %}

The correct syntax is {% endif %}